# How to use an ALIAS in a MYSQL query with aggregate function

Tags: mysql, aggregate, alias, having

I have a working query that returns a single value:

```
SELECT SUM(Stunden) AS sumFixstunden
FROM arbeitszeit
WHERE MONTH(Datum) = 3
```

Now I wanted to change that query using an ALIAS because it would be better for my development environment. I know, that the following query cannot work, using **WHERE**

```
SELECT SUM(Stunden) AS sumFixstunden,
MONTH(Datum) AS Monat
FROM arbeitszeit
WHERE Monat = 3
```

Is there a way to modify that query so that it works using an ALIAS? My attempt was:

```
SELECT SUM(Stunden) AS sumFixstunden,
MONTH(Datum) AS Monat
FROM arbeitszeit
HAVING Monat = 3
```

But this query retrieves an empty result.

I made also some attempts with a SUBQUERY but I had no success.

Comment: I can't see how using an alias could be 'better'..

Comment: I do not create this query myself, it is created by my very special PHP framework. It is important for me to see that it is possible to crate a query of that kiind with an alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT  sumFixstunden, Monat
FROM (
SELECT SUM(Stunden) AS sumFixstunden,
MONTH(Datum) AS Monat
FROM arbeitszeit group by MONTH(Datum)
) as t WHERE t.Monat = 3
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: That's it. Many thanks.
Please change `MONTH(Datus)` to `MONTH(Datum)` in your query snippet (2 appearances). Sorry, it*s German.